# Porting x86_64 Assembly to AArch64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, arm64

I'm trying to convert some existing inline x86_64 assembly to AArch64 compatible version. I am encountering the following errors upon compilation:

```
/tmp/ccSvqF1I.s:72547: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `str [0x4,x1],#0x43e00000'
/tmp/ccSvqF1I.s:72548: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `str [20,x1],2'
```

The x86_64 code below if the original and the AARch64 code is my attempt at porting it.

**x86_64 Assembly:**

```
                __asm__(
                        "incq (%0)\n\t"
                        "jno  0f\n\t"
                        "movl $0x0, (%0)\n\t"
                        "movl $0x43e00000, 0x4(%0)\n\t"
                        "movb %1, %c2(%0)\n"
                        "0:"
                        :
                        : "r"(&op1->value),
                          "n"(IS_DOUBLE),
                          "n"(ZVAL_OFFSETOF_TYPE)
                        : "cc");
```

**AArch64 Assembly**

```
                __asm__(
                        "add %0, %0, #1\n\t"
                        "bvc  0f\n\t"
                        "mov %0, #0x0\n\t"
                        "str [0x4, %0], #0x43e00000\n\t"
                        "str [%c2, %0], %1\n\t"
                        "0:"
                        :
                        : "r"(&op1->value),
                          "n"(IS_DOUBLE),
                          "n"(ZVAL_OFFSETOF_TYPE)
                        : "cc");
```

Edit:Updated with new attempt and error messages

Comment: Not meaning to sound rude, but you should probably try using AArch64 instructions and syntax, as opposed to whatever this is.

Comment: @Notlikethat I guess what my real issue is not understanding the `%c2(%0)` portion of the x86 code. I can't seem to find any documentation that describes what that code does.

Comment: My x86 assembly is rather rusty, and of that my knowledge is of Intel syntax, not GNU's stupid AT&T syntax, but I think that's just base register + immediate offset addressing, with the constraint that `ZVAL_OFFSETOF_TYPE` must be a compile-time constant - see ["x86 Operand Modifiers" in the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm). Either way, any memory operand isn't appropriate for an ARM `mov` instruction.

Comment: @Notlikethat So that line of assembly is moving the value in `%1` into `%c2` offset by the value of `%0`? What would be an alternative to the `mov` instruction for memory operations in ARM? I looked at `str` but that seems to only move a register+offset into a register, which is the opposite of what the x86 code does. I've updated the code with my new attempt and the corresponding error messages.

Comment: The capabilities and syntax of x64 and ARM64 are quite different. Why don't you have the compiler generate an assembly language listing for some C code to see what it expects for ARM64. ARM is a load/store architecture and you can't store immediate values into memory. Instructions can only move register to memory or memory to register.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do something can not be describe by one instruction, you need to split it into several instructions.

The problem is that AArch64 doesn't have an instruction to store immediate value to a memory. You need to move immediate value to an register and then store the register to memory like:

```
movz    w2, #0x43e0, lsl #16         // move #0x43e00000 to a register
str w2, [x1, #20]                    // store to address [x1, #20]
orr w2, wzr, #0x2                    // move #0x2 to a register
str w2, [x1, #4]                     // store to address [x1, #4]
```

ARM instructions are RISC (Reduced instruction set computer) like instructions. The benefit is that instructions are all very simple and fixed length. X86 has more complicated instructions. But you still need to split your behaviour into several instructions if it hasn't an instruction support your behavour.
You can find more information about AArch64 in http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0488d/CIHGGBGB.html.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to use the `ldr=` pseudo-op which would make the cryptic `movz` usage easier to read:

```
ldr  w2, =0x43e00000
str  w2, [x1, #20]
```

.. and so on. Your assembler should be smart enough to realize that it can use `movz` or some other instruction to generate the immediate in `w2`, but in the worst case this'll come out as a literal pool load. While learning, `ldr=` is a boon, and you shouldn't try and game the assembler until you know it's broken or not as efficient as you.

Comment: We need a translator to understand this response.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, almost none of your assembly is correct. The A64 instruction set uses a load/store architecture. This means that there are specific instruction that load and store values from memory into and from registers. No other instructions access memory. So for example an ADD instruction can't access memory. This means that your `add %0, %0, #1` statement doesn't increment `op1->value`, it increments the register that holds the address of `op1->value`. It's basically like you did `op1++` in C instead of `op1->value++`.

```
    zend_long temp;
    static zend_long const overflow = 0x43e0000000000000;
    asm("ldr %[temp], %[value]\n\t"
        "adds %[temp], %[temp], #1\n\t"
        "str %[temp], %[value]\n\t"
        "b.vc 0f\n\t"
        "mov %[temp], #%[overflow]\n\t"
        "str %[temp], %[value]\n\t"
        "mov %w[temp], #%[is_double]\n\t"
        "str %w[temp], %[type_info]\n\t"
        "0:\n\t"
        :
        [temp] "=&r" (temp),
        [value] "+m" (op1->value.lval),
        [type_info] "=m" (op1->u1.type_info)
        :
        [overflow] "N" (overflow),
        [is_double] "M" (IS_DOUBLE)
        : "cc");
```

You'll notice that the x86 INC instruction becomes three separate instructions. The first ones loads the value into a register, the second adds one to the register, and finally the the third stores it back.

The two constants `0x43e000000000000` and `IS_DOUBLE` happen to be ones that can be loaded into a register with a single instruction. Using the MOV pseudo instruction allows allows the assembler to figure out which one. Otherwise instead the LDR= pseudo instruction would have to be used to load the constant from memory. Either way, as claymore said in his answer you can't store an immediate value directly to memory.

Finally the asm statement uses the ADDS instruction instead of the ADD instruction. The former sets the condition flags according the result, the later doesn't. This whole point of the asm statement. It supposed to make signed overflow detection more efficient by checking the condition flags.